# How can I optimize the time of a dataset download from Google Colab?

Tags: download, google-colaboratory

I have to use flicker_8k dataset. So, I have downloaded it on my desktop and access it from Google Colab using the following command:

`from google.colab import files / upload files()`

It has been almost 3 hours since I started, but the dataset is 16% downloaded only, Is there any other way to optimize the time?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you are loading the zipped dataset file or unzipped. I would suggest you to upload the zipped dataset file into your Google Drive. Depending on your internet speed, 1 GB should not take very long. Once you have it there, you can access by mounting your Drive and read it using pandas dataframe function `pandas.read_csv('filename.zip')` .

For mounting the drive, paste these commands on top of your .py file.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
dataset_file_name = os.path.join("/content/gdrive/My Drive", 'filename.zip')
```